# How to use WordPress as home page in Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento-1.7

I'm trying to set up WordPress one page website as home page in Magento. So basically what I would like to create is WordPress split screen website and after you click on section, this will display already built Magento website.

Is anything like that possible to do? If so, can anyone recommend me how to approach this?

Thank you in advance for all replies!

Comment: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/wordpress/how-to-use-wordpress-home-page-in-magento-home-page-cms-page/

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work